# Android- How to use datatable returning web service in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-volley, retrofit

I am new on android. I need some examples or some articles about my situation. Situation is , i have a .net web service that returns DataTable. How can i use it on Android. I see something named Retrofit and Volley. Will these helps me in this situation ? I want to put returned values to `ExpandableListView`. And when i clicked an item , want to go to the details of it. I've worked on SOAP about my Login Activity before. I am waiting for your examples. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Volley or Retrofit to send and retrieve data to/from your web service. Try returning your data as json. You can easily parse it.

Comment: Hi @Nipun. Thanks for your reply. But on web service data is not returning as JSON. So should i return the data as JSON on Web Service ?

Edit : I read your comment again and i just get it. Do you know how can i return DataTable as JSON ? Do you have any links about that ?